# retrieving blob from database loses part of the file

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, binary, blob

I'm having a problem with retrieving some blob data from sql server and processing that in php to convert it back into an image.

Here is an example of one of the blobs (varbinary) in the database:

```
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
```

If i copy and paste that out of the database and do the following:

Pack it into binary:

```
$data = pack("H*", substr($data, 2);
```

Then encode it with base64:

```
base64_encode($data);
```

Then I can print that out and I get the full base64 data, which I can then convert into the image:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAA0JCgsKCA0LCgsODg0PEyAVExISEyccHhcgLikxMC4pLSwzOko+MzZGNywtQFdBRkxOUlNSMj5aYVpQYEpRUk//2wBDAQ4ODhMREyYVFSZPNS01T09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT0//wAARCAD6APoDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDrr9fnUn+7WbKOK1b4Z2H2NZsw4Nejh5e6YSWpBIOOarOOKtyZI5qtIK7YGJWcVA4qw9QtWgyBulRmpWqM1LGRmmEU896aaljG8etNO3pTs47ZpCfalYYKyowZScqcg1btp1+z+WJRE/m72Yj7wqjkd1o+XNQ0mNOxcu1hEYuYchZZyq47KKkhtYhqdzayAsFQmI+pAzVHe3lmIMdh521JJczSuru5LL0PpU8r7lJlmOeOBYDKrefbKV2DG1gfWs/qT7nNO5PJpKErCbuNxRinUlUAhoxS0maQCDjtSknH3cUe1GG9RQMKUDPfFAoIzSGh4Ud2FT2gUXttzz5q/wA6rBRnrU9oCL22x081f51MtjSO56CeGIoxSt96krz2bjSOaTBp5opBcS8HyrWbKOa1LoZjH1rPlQiujDPQ457lV+lVXq1IKrSdK9CBg9ys49agY1YeoGrUCFuaiNSsKjapZSI2ph708000hjfxxTadx6U0ipGAUH0pCq+lSxWskx+RePWtGGxVPmcZ9c1hUrRhuaRptmSEJ+6KNpHUVt+VGh+XA571HcFVf5VVuOe2a5/rivsa+xMkKzA4BNN2nFXw5A3L8qdDimSrggDBRx97HSn9aQvZFGip5YPLx6etRyIUPI49a2hVjPYiUGhh9KTFKaStCBDRgHvS9aTj0NMYvSijI7UtIaAY9DVi1P8Apdv/ANdV/nUCscdKntTm9tv+uq/zqZbFx3PQm60Up6mivNe5uNopR1opCC6O2HPvWa8+3PFaV2P9HPsRWRKOD7V04ZJrU4qi94jZt65xiq71Kv8Aqz9aievQijIrvULVM9QtWo0QtUTVK1RNSYxhphpxppqWMb2rR0/TZLplkKkRD9fWotMsX1C6ES8IOXb0FdPdTx28CRQgBdu1QOprjxFbk0RvShfcoMkcJKxY9z2rPmuD5mBk+pq7cKxjVF/i5NZ12uwrEOW9PSvLbbd2ddrEc0/3TsJPQAd6ryw3Mp3P8noPSp2XYxOenU+9PRTIuCSA35mlewyiqtD1lGe//wBepgDKm0YBbp6UptJHfy4kJx3qY2wtcAuHYenQUOQ1EqkOp2v17ZqwLZ2iYsmM847U2WQbNrJkHv6VYgu2eMISNo+6aam46oTjcy5k8uQrUferlxmdjx8w9O9Uz1r1KFTniclSHKxKOe1JzRk9q3IHc9xRSDd3oFAIcM+tT2p/0y3yf+Wq/wA6r/hU1uf9Ltz/ANNV/nUy2LjueinqaWmFvmNGa81rU6WhSeaTmm55p2aVgsOu/wDj3f8AD+dVPIxZyMBuYpmrV1/qJP8AdNLaEPaqO2CDVQk4xVjllG7MFARAH7MTioZKsMSsYj7ISBVZzXq09Vc5mtSB6hepXqFiM1sBE1RsaexqMn1pMoYaYx9BknoKeataPB9q1e3iI+UNvb6Cs5y5U2OKuzoLa3XS9GAOFlmALnuM1UR1kvJJXOYoE2j3NN1q5F5PLHG3yxHGPXH/ANc1WkPkRRRNwdvmP9T0ryKjb1Z2QVixcT7RhfvnoPSq3lASlnOW25yewqG0mEk0k833EyasWv8ApBBkODJ+8lb+6vZa5nobLUryqFi82X5UHQetV45Z7iTZB8idz3p99cfbJwsYxEp4FWrdBHFsjHJ6mh6I0jG4xUkIMak47nuakW1YYXqauRRYWrEMeZASOKycjVRSMW+tWj+YLle4qvHGIozsOUPTPUV0l5AGRhXNXbeU2BxjrVxdzOa6kG9o5A46qeKZchQ4eP7r8/SlZ97DHcUxWDIyHseK6sPPlkYVI80SPik60dOtG4gcAV6qOIOPU0Z9KNzH0o+tA0KAfWpbfi5g/wCui/zqIGpIv9fD/wBdF/nUS2Lhuegu3zkUB8GoCfnNLmvOe56HISb8mlzUWeaTJ9aQ+RF26/1T/wC4ag0+T5JE9ACKsXH3SPVTWfZPtlf/AK5Z/KtaavA82WjKMjZ3D3NVnNSFssffmoXNepTVkc8tyJqhapWqFjWgiInio2p7VG1JlDSa1fDxW3mu7x/+WUJxWUau2beXp99k8sgwPbNYVtYMuG4WGWIdz88pJP4mo9Sl3zyn1baPoKNKYvJHu5Iy35CqzHeUz/ExJrzJnWglcpBHCOrnmrjS+VZsE+9IdpP86pEhpmkPRRhasRAuI1PYZ/E1jJGsCSztiwBA4rbs7TIyRUFvtQKo61oRzBVHpWD1Oi1loSmBVHakWMKaTz9w64pyMjHlqli1W4kpG05rlNbXbISK6efvg5Fc7raEoDThuNr3THgcEDPY0hk2zHPc1DbnEhB7GifruHY10Lcw6EzjB+tJux2oVtyc9aTdjoK9WlK8TimrMN2e1KKTcT6UA1oSOFSRH9/F/vr/ADqIU+M/vov98fzqJ7M0hud0W+Y0ZqJm+Y0ua8vm1PX5dCTPNJupm6kzS5g5TWuO30rItpMTN7wmtS7bAQ/WsJGxPHz1yv512UFeB41TdEAPzfhTHNJnDkenFNc16MDnluRuahbrUjGoXPNWCGMajJp560w1IwxmrFuT5dwh6NHgfgc1AM9qmiyI5hg5Kjn05rKp8LLhuLpP7uK5kPJSBvwzVPcFI/2VrThTyLHUG4wUQD8ax2PX3rzZnWh4J8o+vWpoJTHIpPSq0m4xNs6jAp21yNwz0GBWLVzWOhuQy+awK1JLcGIGoNAjaS7MZ6EZ+lW/EFqbeMSKODxWDWp0qa2MybUJTwpwKjS/mB/1vFVmjY7fQ9arzW8pnwmdmatRTM23c2U1CUnl80t263Fvx2FUEgfcAO3StJLN0t8v3rJpJmi2ObK7JJKYx3Aj2qzfJskfHpVNmw6j2xW8dTCSsyeP7n4A0uQD0pkJwCp+lPOAetejh37px1VqG7/ZpabkZ6mjvXQZjqen+tj/AN8fzpmOaVf9Yn+8P51nPY0p/EdqT81ANRE/MaA3vXjOWp7qWhKTSZpm7IpM+9K4+U1r9sQIfc/yrn5ZMEEfUVvX6s9sqxglixAH4Gqo0TdbHzJMS44x0FelRqRgrM8Kor2MEv8AOD6mnOahmRop2ikGHRsEU5mr0KbujlkhjGo2NOY1ETzVtiEJ5puaUmmZqRonUjFSRyAHaOSeg9TVTce1TWjBLlWb73Rc9AfWolqio7k96WS0lgJ52Bm+uaowRNO2EBNW5n87U5gfuyphPpWz4dskjs2kYZdmPWvLrOx3U1czIdOkCZZKeLB8gBeK6hlQfeA4qKV4gp4AFcrkzoi/Iq6DbrDJISPmIqbVlE8AjarFgoxvHGelFzEGUnvioewk1znJfZX3FR2qzHp8rYwtWHb7PcBXHXoa1YLhNo6UuZm0lbVFK00sREPKefSrN0qGIqMVNJKjDrVC4fAIBrNhFNnL6kAJWFZcnY44rT1TmYmqgjUwtnv0rpp6mNS1yOE7gW9OtPPWmQqUQg96dXqUI8sThqO7FFLSUZrYzHClU/vE/wB4fzpmaVfvp/vD+dRP4TSn8SOvLc0Bu1Rk80oavAk9T6KK0JM0ZqPdSZpcw+U35rjyYd6YOH2/nXO6hqV5KsmZCvlEEKvGcVr3x/0C5x1WQf0rM1KaFrWEAYkk6gdPxr1KbSdrHgTjomGtqrxR6hHys0ak/WsxjzVlJJJ/Cs8A5ezk5/3aplgQMeld2HeljmqCE5qMmlJppIre5mITTaCab3pMY7PGKaTR3pKljL9iBM0ZP3owSPeug0Vj9jlVuqP+hrmbOTyv3vplfzrqtNQC3kOc7kBrz8TDqdVGQ6abHU1nyStK2xakuyecVXt1Ibnqa85noR2LB1T7PL5RG0AfLVK91qRhtTpU13EsyjI5HQ1lSWzKTnpTSQE/2t72NAR/qz1qeO4ZFwT0qvagRR/WmOx3nHepsXcvC6OetEkxdetUQSBmnq1S0NMyNUkK3mwdMZqupO3mnag+/UHI+lIeMCvQwsLs4MRIDSUE0leijjFopM+tFAC5oz8y/wC8KSkz8y/UfzrOp8LNafxI6stzSg8VGTzRu4r52T1PpYrREm7mkzUZajJqLlWNu8/497xfcH+Vc/fHfEE7ou4H2zW/d9bpfVM1zd0229t8/dkQoa9mm/ePnqi9xEmhTh9Umt5T8t5GUP17VUKmItC/3oyVP4VXZ2tbuOZeGicNV7UmD6ncOv3XYMPxUGu2j8TOSexXY8Uw9aCaaTXQZoD1pM0maTPNK4xc0vUim5oByMVIF6wtWvp4bSLu+Xb0FdWv7q+lywWFVCD3NZGhSR29lNMow0S72Pqewq8kT6ncRNytvGMtjuetcVZ3lZnRT0VxlzxIy1T2Su+6NwKu6jywmAwrkj8qrwZxXnTVmehB3RUne7RiAoqnNPcFdrKc1r3IYr0rJmkcMQ1CdyyDzZgMcU9Fb7zt+FOVS3alYEcUmxDyRioml28+lNdsCoJDuUjPWlYdyj9+5LHuadIfmqQxbJwvp1qOcbZMV34Z6nDXWlyPNHUUGkrvRyh1paSkzQAuaO6/UUlBPI+orOp8LNafxI6YtzQWqPPNKTXzUnqz6eC0Q7dRupmaTdUNmljoLs5lk/2ov6VgzwPO9s0aM5R8kAZrZnkBeI56xc/pVWzmlht28p9nznNe0r82h861emZup2Dr5kpQqCc4I6VRDl41JOWxg/hW6t08+sz2M77vNgGM/wB4ViTRmGRo/Q130nqcMkRk+lITSZpDW9zMXNNJpM8YpKlsY7NKKYSFHJqMTfOMDis5VEikmzf0iXfDc2wHzSgBRXVBP7O0kqibnVMY/vMa5XwbEZ9ZlmP3Yo/1NdwQD1Ga86tO8jeOiOfs4pZNF8q8GJg7Z9jmq9s2yQrJwa3LxQg3AYDnJ+tY13HuOV4Nc0tTrpu6LDFCMHFUZo4mc5AqnLcyxEhucVVe7cnvSUWaqaNNUhRTjGapXLIoJGKqm5YjHNRMzP16Uco+dMGbceKZMCIiR14qVVoZPMlhgHWRwKEJvQWW1kXS11Ej5RJ5ZHt61n3T7ViY9SCDXaazDHbeGbuPA2xoD+NefTTeZFECeQCTW9JuLujlqakwcN0NLn0qmDjvTxIVPWu2NfuczgWaSohMD1qQMD0NbKaexNmhc80h7fWikJzj60qnwsun8SOjzyMUhNNJxSFq+Ym9WfUw2Q/NLUe6k31JZ1FtohjcSPMWYdOOKr31kbG0kIIcu4wO+PatCae9lIWFBDHvIMjcnA9qeYUAkuJD5jqCyg+uK9uN07s+W53axxM15v1NrmNAjRjge49aZcS+cwfP3hzVu20LUJVMvlELOpPv1qve2MlgVidSM85Peu6m1cxZUNNwScCnEetQSynovAq5zUSErjncLwDk1E8x6Co80xjzXPKbZoojy+e9CtUWeaUGs2xnZ+ASD9uH8W5fyxXX1wfga58rV5rdiMTR5H1Fd5XNNalEN5CZrV0U4bqv1rnxMJUyRgg4IPY101c5rlq9pcG7iUmGQ/vAP4T61m1c3pTtozPuowwyKznQDPFaQkEg4NV5YwcnvSTsbvUobeTT1WpPLpyrgUmOIwLU2i27XmuxOB+7t/nY/wAqglZiViiGZHOFFdTptgumaeU4Mj8u3qacUTORneMLlU0CZc4aaQKB6ivP/StrxTfG51DyVb93DxjPesUc5zW8Ec03qLnmgmkFIasgeDxQrEUxTS0XsBYWYEc0/PT0yKqZqRZCODyK0VV2sxxWp1zJDJgwyD6NUMsMidR+VZ6yBkR43yGqVLyaLgk4/OvGqQ1Z9DTqe6iXdS7hSpdwyj94gB9Vpc2//PQ/lWPKaqaPQXUMhX1qpNkLjKjI289qsW4lWLEzBmz1A7VWnAlZdjKfMOAK9envY+WehYtJA8QHHy/yrlvF13BNcQRRMGeEncewz2pupaq9oWggYrIQVfHauZkckkkkknmuiMOWV7ivcV3561Wc80rnNRlsnFU3cEhc01jxTQccUMcipuMTNKDimA5pQaQGho119k1i0uM4CyAN9DxXq+c8jpXjLE7TjqORXq+h3ovtGtbgHJZAG+orCotblIv02RFkjZHAKsMEGlorMDldR0eW3ZpLQFk67O4rNjl3cMOa7hx3HWsjUtLhuGaSDCSjrjvQzohPuYQQGopiEWrLwTwcSxkAd+1P0+xbULxFwfKQ7nPbHpSsaN2RZ8OaYTIb24Hzf8swew9a0NevFstOmmJ5VePc1neJdfTS41tbEqZwQWI6KB2rltd199Ut4Y9pTHLjPBNWo3MG+pjO7SOzscsxyaQdKTvSitkrGTDOKbSk4pKAEVsNzTz61EetPU5FJgOJozxTTSZpMaLun3f2aYF1DxnhlNbO62uBmN9h9Grms1ftGEsRVuq1zVoLc78LWa90vy2zLyB+IqLDf3jSRzzQ/cbI9DUv2/1txXLZnoXieoFsEYBJ9q437VItxOIyw8uWQZJ565wK6B9bgTOEY1yt1d5nuJfLAEpZvpmvVoySPn5QfUy72c3F3LMx5ds1UZuaHPeo92RWzZnYGPNRMcGnE4pjVJQE96M8U0HikzSAAecUveo8807OKAJAa7HwDf8AFxpznofMjHt3riweat6XfNp2qW92pOEbDD1U9aiSuiket7qGIVCSQAOpNZuo65p+nwCWSYOzDKop5NcNrXiS81NigYxQ9kX+tZKLZR0mu+K4LVGgsCJZuhfstcnZ63fWl006zszMcuGOQayyc96TNacisLmfQ7eHxfbup8+3OT1A5BqjfeJ38loLCMW8R9Op/GuWyQcihnLdTmp5EVz6CzTPI5ZiST1JqIntQT2pMVaIbuKKUHrSE0h60AKTk0uaaOtLSuA1qVD2oPIpg4agCRjikJ6CgnikB5pDFbsKtae2Ljaf4hVQ8mnxNskVvQ1E1dGlKXLJM2GXmmYNS5zz60mK8+57O+penknSTYznOAeKrTMwiYsT6Vp3kAjmAbBLAuD14J4rN1EgRoo7nmvaSS2PAk2UGOc1CeDTmbBpjnvQ2SBIppNNzTc84qRik0jHikakzkUgEpQeKaaUHtQA7Jpc03NGaQx7yM2NzE445pN3vTM0A0APzTSc0maTPpQAucUhNITSUAL3oFJmjNIYp96SgmkHJoAUUd6KSgBaaetKTTWpAOzxRSdqM8UgAHmnjqajXpTl64HJoY0bFpJ5lspPUcVNVWxXZEQepOcVarz6sbSPZoSvBGve5W/nXOQG45zjjNY+pP8AvVHoK1r+QtqV0OyMEHGO3X9azr0RuFzjcOteomeNNamWx4phParTQKw+U4qtJCyn1p3IIjweaaT3px9+tMNIAByOaQHt3pM4NJ/FQA7NNB+akNL9KVxj+1JmkHSkJzQAoPNGfSmg0uaAFpM0hNJk0AOopKKADPFAoopABNA60hpaBi0maTNITSAXPNIetHeg+1MAPSm5PApSeKETc3XA9aQCgGp4dqfM3WmybQAkYye5pViPGTikwRatZWe4yOFxV7ms0SLCuE+9jrV5JlKKSRyK5asLu56GGqWjZm3qURi1CZwPllw3XOG7isO+RzO7DocVs3//AB8D/dqhc/eP4V3pHBPcyzJInc0hnZhg4qaf7tVW6UcpAjtnqOabjI46UrdaWLpRYCF+KaG5qxc/dNVR1o5QuPzQDTR1pf8AGiwri5pM0h60HrRyjuO+lFNWn0rBcaTSDpTjQelOwriUtN7070pWC4cetHFIaDRyjuHFGQaO1C9KXKFwOKTindqZRYLigilyKOxobpRyjuMb260/YVX600fep5osFxyMqfWkact06VG1C0uUY9TnrS+awGPShOgph6molE0ps//Z
```

All well and good.

Now if I try and do this with a script... So first I select the data from the db:

```
$s = odbc_prepare($ebs, "select TOP 1 
                         binary_object as img
                         from BLOBS
                         where owner_ref = 271040");

$q = odbc_execute($s);
$record = odbc_fetch_object($s);
```

Then I encode that data into base64, then it looks as if it's worked, but I actually only get about 2/3 of the data:

```
echo ( base64_encode($record->img) );

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
```

To answer a question I can forsee. I cannot pack the data that comes straight out of the database like that, because when I echo it out its a load of gibberish that starts with:

```
ÿØÿàJFIF``ÿÛC      ' .)10.)-,3:J>36F7
```

Does anyone have any idea where I might be going wrong?

Cheers.

**EDIT** Just to clarify as well, I think whatever is wrong is how I am selecting the data, because if I simply set the file header to image/jpeg and echo out $record->img without changing anything, I get about two thirds of the image, then the bottom bit is cut off.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this working now. The problem was in the php.ini settings for odbc.

By default odbc has a byte limit of 4096 for data returned, so it was cutting it off at that point.

By changing this in php.ini

```
odbc.defaultlrl = 60000
```

I am now able to get all the data back and construct the image fully.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a bit and came across an interesting bit of information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php):

> Base64-encoded data takes about 33% more space than the original data.

It sounds like the encoded string does not have enough memory. I can only guess, why that would be, but maybe the echo-command (or something else) only reserves enough space for $record->img?
Maybe you can try to store the encoded string in a variable with more space before echo-ing it?

I hope this helps at...

Comment: Hi, Same thing happens when I store in a variable and echo it out.

Comment: OK. Next idea: what if you use an encoding function in your sql statement? (like TO_BASE64 in mysql or utl_encode.base64_encode in oracle)

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same issue on our WAMP server. We switched from an oracle database to a MsSql database.  The old oracle server was set up years ago so we are not sure of the settings (none of us had access to it) and the php code for oracle addressed the size in the code.  There was nothing comparable in php for mssql that would do this, and even when we tried to force the size in the header it did nothing.  Finally found this and some other articles and by changing 4 different php.ini files in our servers we were able to show the entire image by increasing the file size to 60000  We had to update php.ini  php.ini-development php.ini-production and phpforApache on the odbc.defaultlrl line and increase them from the 4096 to 60000.